# Labview: increasing the capacity of a text indicator

Tags: text, scrollbar, labview, indicator

I have a (multiline) text indicator in my program where I display everything that my program does. Every time after adding new string to the indicator, I move the vertical scroll bar to the end to make sure that the user will see the message instantaneously. It works fine.

However, when there is a lot of text in the indicator, the user is unable to move the scroll bar. Also, the scroll bar doesn't move to the bottom of the indicator after adding a new message.

How can I increase the capacity of my text indicator? Is it even possible or do I have to decrease the amount of text I display?

The rest of the program works well, the screen doesn't freeze. The only problem I have is that the vertical scroll bar doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 2):

LabVIEW stores strings as a pointer to a structure containing a 4-byte length value followed by a 1D array of byte integers (8-bit characters). The 4-byte value is the same size as a U32, which has a 2^32 range (0 to 4,294,967,295). So, your string can have up to 4,294,967,295 characters.

About the second part of your question: http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/E888D1D6A739A787862571F800586482

Comment: 2^32 is a huge number and I'm sure my string isn't so big. I know how to make the scroll scroll down after adding some text. I already implemented it. The problem is that when the text in the indicator is very long, scrolling the scrollbar (either programmatically after adding another text (200 characters at most) or by the user) has no effect.

Comment: Than, can you check your system RAM?

Comment: I have 8 GB RAM memory and my string had approximately 400 000 characters.

Answer (score 2):

Put a gigantic amount of text in your indicator while the VI is in edit mode. Can you move the scrollbar then? If you can, then I suspect the problem is how you're adjusting the scrollbar at run time. Is it possible that you're continuously setting the scroll position to the bottom so your user tries to drag it and fails?

Comment: I put a gigantic amount of text in the indicator and I was able to move the scroll bar in the text mode. I think it is possible that I set the scroll position to the bottom so often that the user has no chance to drag it. But it doesn't explain why  setting the position programmatically failed when I had huge amount of text in the indicator.  In this case the order  is clear: add new line->set the scroll bar position-> do sth->add new line.

Comment: It sounds like you're on the right track... you probably want to do this: Read the scroll position property BEFORE you set new text. Then set the new text. If and only if the position was at the bottom of the old text then move it to the bottom of the new text. That way when your user drags it off the bottom, you stop scrolling until they put it back on the bottom. I know several logging applications that have this behavior.